# How to Use Passport JS with MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, passport.js

I would like to ask about how to make passport js functioning with MySQL Database, I have searched all around and get one but I am confused to integrate the code because I think it was a different version of express js. For me, the documentation didn't help so much at all since I am really stuck with Javascript. So here is my work

```
// config/passport.js

// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;

// load up the user model
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'IP',
      user: 'root',
      password: 'password'
    });

connection.query('USE ecommerce');
// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function(passport) {

    // =========================================================================
    // passport session setup ==================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // required for persistent login sessions
    // passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ",[id], function(err, rows){
            done(err, rows[0]);
        });
    });

    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL SIGNUP ============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

    passport.use(
        'local-signup',
        new LocalStrategy({
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) {
            // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
            // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?",[username], function(err, rows) {
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (rows.length) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That username is already taken.'));
                } else {
                    // if there is no user with that username
                    // create the user
                    var newUserMysql = {
                        username: username,
                        password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, null, null)  // use the generateHash function in our user model
                    };

                    var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users ( email, password ) values (?,?)";

                    connection.query(insertQuery,[newUserMysql.username, newUserMysql.password],function(err, rows) {
                        newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

                        return done(null, newUserMysql);
                    });
                }
            });
        })
    );

    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL LOGIN =============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

    passport.use(
        'local-login',
        new LocalStrategy({
            // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
            usernameField : 'email',
            passwordField : 'password',
            passReqToCallback : true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
        },
        function(req, username, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?",[username], function(err, rows){
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (!rows.length) {
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
                }

                // if the user is found but the password is wrong
                if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password))
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong password.')); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

                // all is well, return successful user
                return done(null, rows[0]);
            });
        })
    );
};
```

here is the other:

```
//app.js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection  = require('express-myconnection');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var product = require('./routes/product');
var auth = require('./routes/auth');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// using mysql to connect database
app.use(connection(mysql,{
  host: '139.59.228.233',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'grandchase',
  database: 'ecommerce'
},'request')
);

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//Routes
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/product', product);
app.use('/auth', auth);

//Express Passport JS
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

var User = {
      usernameField: 'euser',
      passwordField: 'epass'
};

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('404', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('404', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Here is the route:

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  // res.render('index', { title: 'Marketplace Untuk Anda' });
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login',
                                   failureFlash: true })
});

router.post('/register', function(req,res,next){
  passport.authenticate('local-signup',{ successRedirect: '/',
                                  failureRedirect: '/login' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The view routes are working but I am stuck at login and register here, Can anyone help me?

Thank you so much

Comment: I couldn't understand what is your problem exactly. But I can suggest you that repository.
https://github.com/manjeshpv/node-express-passport-mysql
This might be helpful for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, actually my problem is I cannot login or signup using these code, I have clone that repo but I cannot integrate it into Express 4, The problem is when I post to my route, the browser is not responding and the error. :(

Comment: Could you please paste your full error?

Comment: It is actually no error in my console (and I don't know where to put the console.log for the error),

Comment: Well, please share your whole project with me, I'll have a look it tonight.

Comment: Do you have a github account? I can invite you then sir

Comment: Yes. My username is AOnurOzcan

Comment: I have invited you sir, please accept it

Comment: Hi, I tried but actually can't modified your code. I strongly recommend you this repo. It will help you I'm sure. Sorry.

https://github.com/manjeshpv/node-express-passport-mysql

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time... Well, I will look at it again if that repo can help me